# Flutter : How to navigate to the new screen using json and listview

Tags: flutter, http, listview, navigation

I started Flutter just right now. I'm studying http, Json 'title' text lists are showed on my app.

My next step is to navigate to new screen that shows json 'body' text lists When I tap json 'title' text lists

But I couldn't find any clues. I Don't know what to do, where to start..... could you help me? any tip or advice?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    this.setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    });

    print(data[1]["title"]);

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new ListTile(title: new Text(data[index]["title"]));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxzQg.png)

Comment: Hi There. This will definitely help you a lot. i just started learning flutter too. :D https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onTap` properties in `ListTile`.

```
 return new ListTile(
     onTap:(){
       // Navigator code
     }
title: new Text(data[index]["title"]));
```